# Find the interval where the solution exists (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find the interval where the solution exists of the following ODE and initial condition:
$ty' + 4y=2t^2, y(3)=1$

My attempt:

If I solve this with integrating factor, I get the solution $y=\frac{1}{3}t^2-\frac{2*3^4}{t^4}$. Clearly, $y$ has a discontinuity at $t=0$, so the solution is not defined there, but the initial ODE is also discontinous there. Here comes my question: Is it correct to say that the solution exists for $t\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ or should it instead be that the solution exists for $t\in(0,\infty)$ since the initial condition is in this interval? And should you reach this conclusion at the very beginning of the problem rather than at the end, because to find the integrating factor requires writing the ODE on standard form and thus dividing by t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the expression itself is defined on $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$, the solution of the IVP has always only a single interval as domain, here due to the initial point thus $(0,\infty)$.

For linear DE the maximal domain is always the largest interval containing the initial point where the coefficient functions and right side are continuous, and the leading coefficient is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks! So there can never be any other discontinuities (besides the ones that can directly be observed from the ODE itself) that can only be seen after you actually solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, *linear* DE, higher order as well as systems, have this property.

Comment: Great. So for non-linear do I need to actually solve the problem to see where the solution is defined? I remember something about there being a theorem that says that in the non-linear case $y'=f(t,y)$, if $f(t,y)$ is continuous then the solution exists?

Comment: In the general case you only get the existence of local solutions. Usually these can be extended to the boundary of the domain, but that boundary might be in state space direction at a finite time. That's why there is an interest in bounded and sub-linear $f$, trapping regions and similar restrictions to a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Just two questions about your first sentence: "In the general case you only get the existence of local solutions." General means non-linear, right? And what do you mean with "get the existence of local solutions"? Is that when you solve it you only get local solutions, or is it that f being continuous only tells you about the existence of local solutions?

Comment: The second. It is extremely rare outside of textbook exercises to get symbolic expressions for the solution of non-linear DE. So the best you can get is local existence and some regularity statements, meaning the solution is in general not less smooth than the right side.

Comment: Perfect. Just to clarify that I fully understand everything. In the general case (for textbook exercises), I need to find the solution of the ODE to understand the interval of existence. To find the interval of existence, I look at this solution and look for potential discontinuous, and I also try to find whether there are any discontinuities when I plug this solution into the ODE. By doing these two things, I can then find an interval for the independent variable, $t$ in this case, for which the solution exists. Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the procedure for examples like $y'=y^2$ or $y'=y^2+1$. As another well-explored system, for the Lorenz attractor system one can not find symbolic solutions, but one can show that solutions stay bounded in forward time.